# Telerik Test Studio - How to send a simple ESC key?

Tags: c#, telerik-test-studio

I've tried a few things that I found online but I'm not able to just send a simple KeyPress of the "ESC" key into my tests.

I just want to send the "ESC" key on my C# test code and using Telerik Test studio to run the test.

What do I need? Isn't this enough??

```
SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
```

Comment: At some point of the code, I wish to give the instruction to press ESC on the application, anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 :
Add an Assembly Reference to System.Windows.Forms (in case it's not already added)

STEP 2 :
In place of - `SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");`

Use this code below:

```
Manager.Desktop.KeyBoard.SendString("{ESC}");
```